# how to call an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, clojure, database-cursor

How to call an Oracle stored procedure which takes a string and a date as input and returns a refcursor as output using Clojure?

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec SOMEDB.PKG.GETPOSITIONS('ABC', to_date('2012-02-07','yyyy-mm-dd'), :rc)
print rc
```

Comment: are you using java.jdbc: https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it. I have included a few helper `fn`'s that I use to convert strings to SQL dates.

```
(ns foo
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.string :as cs]))

(def conn
  {:classname "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   :subprotocol "oracle:thin"
   :subname "@//host.name.here:port.here/db.here"
   :user "user"
   :password "pass"})

(defonce ORACLE_CURSOR oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes/CURSOR)

(defn date-to-sql-date [date]
  (java.sql.Date. (.getTimeInMillis
                    (java.util.GregorianCalendar.
                      (+ (.getYear date) 1900) (.getMonth date) (.getDate date)))))

(defn string-to-sql-date [date]
  ;; assumes American date formats
  (if-not (empty? date)
    (date-to-sql-date (java.util.Date. (cs/replace date #"-" "/")))))

(jdbc/with-connection conn
  (with-open [stmt (.prepareCall (jdbc/connection) "{ call SOMEDB.PKG.GETPOSITIONS(?, ?, ?) }")]
    (doto stmt
      (.setString 1 "ABC")
      (.setDate 2 (string-to-sql-date "2012-02-07"))
      (.registerOutParameter 3 ORACLE_CURSOR)
      (.execute))
    (resultset-seq (. stmt getObject 3)))) ;; lazy-sequence
```

[resultset-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/resultset-seq)

**NOTE:** you may need to consume the entire sequence if you plan on returning it from a `fn` since the connection will close as soon as the `fn` returns.